# Object Detection by giving an input image using opencv

Tags: object, opencv, video, detection, tagging

I'm new to opencv .My requirement is that in a video by giving an input image it should tag every occurence of the image in the video using opencv. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [OpenCV Template Matching](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html)

where you have to extract each frame your video and apply Template Matching.
You can see OpenCV video tutorial [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-write/video-write.html). Also see OpenCV documentation [Reading and Writing Images and Video](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html).

Answer (score 0):

Load the input image in a global cv:Mat.
Scale this image appropriately, make this the template image(or Mat).

First load the video, then extract each frame out of it and store in a local cv::Mat.
Run template matching as suggested in the tutorial given by Harris with the local frame.
If match found, mark the frame and position using some GUI or color whatever.
Repeat process for next frame.